# Calculate Heat of Atomisation

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, heat, free-energy, sublimation

[image]What is heat of atomisation of P4O6(s) Given heat of sublimation of P4O6 is x kJ/mol & P–O bond energy is y kJ/mol.

What is heat of atomisation of P4O6(s) Given heat of sublimation of P4O6 is x kJ/mol & P–O bond energy is y kJ/mol.

Comment: Is it $x + 12y$ ?

Comment: yes the ans is x+12y ... @SoumikDas can u please let me know the solution i am stuck up...please asap     thanks in advance!

Comment: Do u know the structures of $\ce{P4O6}$  and  $\ce{P4O10}$ where two six membered heterocyclic rings are fused together ?

Comment: @SoumikDas i just know the individual structures of p4o6 and p4o10 not the fused one....please help!!

Comment: See this https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-4a50afc1084fa22bd3a7f0ae8756dee7  and  https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0079670015000088-sc2.gif

Comment: From the two pictures clearly you can easily count how many $\ce{P-O}$ bonds will be broken ?

Comment: @SoumikDas but what is the need of counting P-O-P bonds in P4O10??

Comment: Just saying. You don't need them in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Without just giving you the answer:

Enthalpy of atomisation is "the enthalpy change that accompanies the total separation of all atoms in a chemical substance". You can read up more about it on Wikipedia[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_atomization).

1. Look up the chemical compound shape and connection
2. Add up the number of connections
3. Include the heat of sublimation
4. You should have a reliable answer and know how to do future problems similar to this,

Also, see the comment from @gaurang-tandon